# javascript if else using math adding value to field not working

Tags: javascript, if-statement, math

Cant get this to work, getting blind staring at it. 
Any ideas? 
Trying to put the value ***kg*** into the field ***lbh*** if it is higher than the product of ***m3total** (**l*****b*****h**/100000/00035)*. It is used to calculate the fright price for a shipment.

It uses to calculations in the if else and i'm thinking im missing something here.

```js
function add() {
  var m3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("m3").value);
  var kg = parseInt(document.getElementById("kg").value);
  var l = parseInt(document.getElementById("L").value);
  var b = parseInt(document.getElementById("B").value);
  var h = parseInt(document.getElementById("H").value);
  var x = 0.0035;
  var y = 3350;


  var total = 0;
  kg = +kg || 0
  m3 = +m3 || 0
  l = +l || 0
  b = +b || 0
  h = +h || 0
  total = Math.ceil((m3total / 0.0035));
  kgtotal = (kg + 0)
  m3total = (l * b * h) / 1000000;
  (document.getElementById("m3").value) = m3total;
}
if ((total > kgtotal)) {

  (document.getElementById("LBvekt").value) = total;

} else if ((total < kgtotal)) {
  (document.getElementById("LBvekt").value) = kgtotal;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button</p>

<button onclick="add()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>


<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
    <div class="row gutter-sm">


      <div class="col-sm-3 m-b-15 m-sm-b-0">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="kg" name="kg" placeholder="KG" onChange="add()">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 m-b-15 m-sm-b-0">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="m3" name="m3" placeholder="m3" readonly>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 m-b-15 m-sm-b-0">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="LBvekt" id="LBvekt" placeholder="LBvekt">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
    <div class="row gutter-sm">


      <div class="col-sm-3 m-b-15 m-sm-b-0">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="L" name="L" placeholder="L (cm)">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 m-b-15 m-sm-b-0">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="B" name="B" placeholder="B (cm)">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 m-b-15 m-sm-b-0">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="H" name="H" placeholder="H (cm)" onChange="add()">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the code in your snippet is your actual code, your `if` statement only executes once: when the page loads. It is outside of your `add()` function so it only executes when it is loaded.

Most likely you want to put your `if` statement inside of the `add()` function like this:

```js
function add() {
  var m3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("m3").value);
  var kg = parseInt(document.getElementById("kg").value);
  var l = parseInt(document.getElementById("L").value);
  var b = parseInt(document.getElementById("B").value);
  var h = parseInt(document.getElementById("H").value);
  var x = 0.0035;
  var y = 3350;


  var total = 0;
  kg = +kg || 0
  m3 = +m3 || 0
  l = +l || 0
  b = +b || 0
  h = +h || 0
  m3total = (l * b * h) / 1000000;
  total = Math.ceil((m3total / 0.0035));
  kgtotal = (kg + 0)
  
  (document.getElementById("m3").value) = m3total;
  if ((total > kgtotal)) {

    (document.getElementById("LBvekt").value) = total;

  } else if ((total < kgtotal)) {
    (document.getElementById("LBvekt").value) = kgtotal;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button</p>

<button onclick="add()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>


<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
    <div class="row gutter-sm">


      <div class="col-sm-3 m-b-15 m-sm-b-0">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="kg" name="kg" placeholder="KG" onChange="add()">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 m-b-15 m-sm-b-0">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="m3" name="m3" placeholder="m3" readonly>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 m-b-15 m-sm-b-0">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="LBvekt" id="LBvekt" placeholder="LBvekt">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
    <div class="row gutter-sm">


      <div class="col-sm-3 m-b-15 m-sm-b-0">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="L" name="L" placeholder="L (cm)">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 m-b-15 m-sm-b-0">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="B" name="B" placeholder="B (cm)">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 m-b-15 m-sm-b-0">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="H" name="H" placeholder="H (cm)" onChange="add()">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just about to post a similar answer. Mine also includes moving `m3total = (l * b * h) / 1000000;` before `total = Math.ceil((m3total / 0.0035));` as it makes more sense (I think?).

Comment: Good call on that, didn't even catch that.

Comment: Thanks guys.. solved it for me, just needed to move it around like this:

Comment: m3total = (l * b * h) / 1000000;
 (document.getElementById("m3").value) = m3total;
  total = Math.round(m3total / 0.0035);
  kgtotal = Math.round(kg)

Comment: Never saw the missing }